# Trying to fill a colored line above filled in cells

Tags: vba, colors, named-ranges

[image: No Colored Rows][image: With Colored Rows]
My code is to fill color into rows above filled in rows.
There is 2 rows above the text it's the bottom row of the 2 needs to fill in color?
They should be linked to the ranges shown in the Sub above the Function
What I can't really understand that it seemed to work the other day but now it`s stopped working?
I think the sub is right just the Function seems to be failing??
Not sure how to link the 2 together?

```
   Private Sub Fill_Color_Click()
   Dim Com As ComboBox
   Dim ws As Worksheet

   Set Com = Me.Fill_Color

   With ws
   
    Select Case Com.Value
        Case ("Fill Color 1 Page Job Card")
            Color .Range("A13:Q61")

        Case ("Fill Color 2 Page Job Card")
            Color .Range("A13:Q61")
            Color .Range("A66:Q120")
   
        Case ("Fill Color 3 Page Job Card")
             Color .Range("A13:Q61")
            Color .Range("A66:Q122")
            Color .Range("A127:Q178")
            
        Case ("Fill Color 4 Page Job Card")
            Color .Range("A13:Q61")
            Color .Range("A66:Q122")
            Color .Range("A127:Q183")
            Color .Range("A188:Q244")

        Case ("Fill Color 5 Page Job Card")
            Color .Range("A13:Q61")
            Color .Range("A66:Q122")
            Color .Range("A127:Q183")
            Color .Range("A188:Q244")
            Color .Range("A249:Q299")
    End Select
    
End With


End Sub

Function Color(rng As Range)

Dim row As Range
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Card Master")
Dim EmptyRowNum As Integer

For i = 1 To rng.Rows.Count

    Set row = rng.Rows(i)
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(row) = 0 Then
        EmptyRowNum = EmptyRowNum + 1
    End If
    If EmptyRowNum = 2 Then
        EmptyRowNum = 0
        row.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
    End If

Next i

End Function
```

Comment: I do not understand anything from your question, sorry... Please, try editing your question and put a picture with the initial situation and another one (at least) with what you need to accomplish.

Comment: Where and how is `Com.Value` declared and assigned a value?

Comment: What errors do you get when you attempt to debug? Why have you not corrected those errors? Or, if you need help with them, why don't you mention them?

Comment: I`ve shown 2 pictures above which should explain what is happening. Sorry to be thick I`ve declared com.Value now.

Comment: It won`t fire the code up so there is not any Errors?

Comment: Thank you for editing. Based on the sub name `Fill_Color_Click()` I would expect the code to be triggered by something clickable like e.g. a button.

Answer (score 0):

You have a naming error, `sheet` vs `ws`: `Dim sheet as Worksheet` in the `Color()` function but then you set `ws = ...`.

Anyway, it is misplaced, you need to move it to `Fill_Color_Click()`:

```
Private Sub Fill_Color_Click()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Card Master")
```

so that the references to the ranges make sense.

Comment: I did what you said and it seemed to work 2 or 3 times now it`s stopped working ?

Comment: Well, I hope you do understand that I cannot see your desk from here, and I have no means to guess what the problem might be. My test code here works as many times as I hit the button that triggers my test. You need to do some debugging. Start by setting a breakpoint on the line `Set ws = ...` and then activate the `Fill_Color_Click()`. Execution stops at the breakpoint. Now you can step forward, one line at a time, with the F8 -key. Where does execution deviate from what you expect it to do. At that point, what and why do you expect it to do and what does it do?

Comment: I`ve tried to do the F8 test but it jumps over the code. Could I send my workbook to you?

Comment: Sorry, no. That is not how SO works. It is important that you communicate the steps you have taken, kind of verify that you did understand and you did actually do what I asked you to. 1) did you manage to set a breakpoint on `Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Job Card Master")`? 2) Is that the first execution line in `Fill_Color_Click()`? 3) What triggers the `Fill_Color_Click()`

Comment: I did set a breakpoint on ("Jobcard Master"). but no joy?. What triggers it is a combobox command. It`s still jumping over the code??

Comment: We are in a dead end in that case. I did show you how to make a correction to the code you presented (Moving some code from `Function Color()` to `Sub Fill_Color_Click()`). In my test the corrected code performs as expected. With that I consider that I have answered your original question. It now seems you have another problem related to triggering the code. That is a different topic, and you should ask a new question.

Comment: Have you checked that all cells in the rows that appear to be empty, actually are empty. Maybe you don't have 2 consecutive empty rows?

Comment: Please read the documentation for `WorksheetFunction.CountA()` and the first note: *A value is any type of information, including error values and empty text (""). A value does not include empty cells.* The assignment of "" to the cells in column `P` prevents your code from working correctly. I suggest you exclude the checking of cells in columns `O`, `P` and `Q`